# Is it legal to create/build buildings and architecture for a game like gta, nfs mw, etc from a real city?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, communityengine

I want to start game development and thought to work on a gaming engine like Unreal Engine or Unity Engine and thought of building a real life game around me. Is it legal to build a game on a real city architecture? I live in India.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the Help Centre.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consult with a competent lawyer in your area to avoid a lawsuit (*an example can be found in the link below*).

Note: "Is it legal" questions are not best suited to the stack overflow format.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/can-you-use-well-known-buildings-in-your-game

Comment: This was a big discussion back in the day and usually the answer is no, your not allowed to, but consult a lawyer familiar with this issue.